# How can I extract voice memos from a large set of JPGs?

Tags: images, metadata, voice

I have thousands of JPEG files from many different photographers. Some of the files have embedded voice memos (a short audio recording of the photographer speaking into the camera's microphone to describe the photo).

How can I extract all of the audio voice memos from these files?

Comment: How did they put these audio segments into the pictures? They must have used some program. You have to determine which program it was in order to know how to decrypt it.  It could be encrypted into the picture in many different ways.

Comment: One by one I suspect.

Comment: One of them used a feature on his Nikon camera, not separate software.

Answer (score 0):

Use [exiftool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftool)

exiftool -VOICEMEMOTAG -w! *.jpg

Comment: This is only true if they were put on using exiftool as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no an standard method for embedding audio on JPEG, each camera vendor could be using its own way.

Check this project that could be useful for some of them http://regenerus.com/projects/audionet/